# How do I find out whether this definite integral's limit exists?

Tags: limits

I'm trying to find out whether or not the limit of this integral exists:
$$\int_a^bdx{1\over \sqrt{b^2-x^2}}$$
I can't figure out which test to use to see if it converges (or doesn't). I tried to turn the integral into a summation $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i^*)\Delta{x}$ where $x_i^*$ = $x_i-x_{i-1}$ and $\Delta{x}={{b-a}\over n}$. I tried to plug these things into the summation but it was very messy and I didn't get anywhere. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Do you know the derivative of $\arcsin x$ or $\arccos x$?

Comment: Think about enforcing the substitution $x=b \sin\theta$.

Comment: With _the limit of this integral exists:_ you mean the integral by the definition of Riemann integral?